# How to specify a password with shp2pgsql using CentOS?

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, centos, shp2pgsql

I'm developing a python script that uses shp2sql via subprocess.call().

The string I'm using works fine on Linux Mint:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 ../data/download.shp ccd_hoods_new | psql -h hostname -d databasename -U username -P password -q
```

However, when I run the script on CentOS, I'm prompted for a password, which presents a new problem when deploying and automating via CRON.

The only documentation I can find is [this cheatsheet](http://bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide.bqg), which confirms that I'm doing things correctly.

But why on the CentOS machine would it not be recognizing the -P flag?

Both servers are running the same script that points to the same host running PostgreSQL 9.6 and PostGIS 2.4.

Comment: There is a space between - and P. If not a typo, try removing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-P` argument to `psql` is not used to supply a password; see the documentation at [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

You can supply a password to `psql` using one of three methods:

1. Enter the password at a prompt
2. Enter the password in your `~/.pgpass` file
3. Set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable

Maybe your Mint system has the password defined using #2 or #3? If not, perhaps the server has disabled authentication when connecting from certain IP addresses.

EDIT by @DPSSpatial

2. works by constructing the following command:

   ```
   shp2pgsql -s 4326 ../data/download.shp ccd_hoods_new | PGPASSWORD=password psql -h hostname -d database -U username -q
   ```

I found this syntax from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953448/1704448

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit I made, but that got me on the right track... thanks again!