# Uploading shapefile to PostGIS database using PHP

Tags: postgis, postgresql, php

I want to insert a shapefile into a PostGIS database using PHP.  I go through the examples and I tried the following:

```
$command = 'shp2pgsql -s 2100 -d /D:\CHECK DATA-group\2016\Ayomi\JULY\12FCP151Sup88Sh99\121800151s00088s0099\CM121800151s00088s0099Poly.shp | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d ssh -U postgres';
```

But it is not working. Then in the forum, I saw an instruction to add the `exec($command,$out,$ret);` to the above code.  Can any one explain me what is meant by `$out,$ret` variables?

Comment: no i don't get any errors?even after i add "exec($command,$out,$ret);" it doesn't generate any errors.but shape file has not tranfer to the data base

Comment: 1) this is run on the server, so make sure that the shp is indeed on the server (not your local D drive). 2) there is a space in your path, which is likely to break the command. Try adding double quotes around the path

Comment: I am new to this type of scripts.Actually,this is in my dektop.i have installed wamp and postgres sql in my desktop.What my plan was try this in my desktop first and then use it in the  server with changes.According to my current environment, should I change the above script totally?

Comment: can you please tell me where is the space exits.You meant space between  equal (= ) sign and 'shp2pgsql?

Comment: He meant the space in the file path near `CHECK DATA`. Try using `$command = 'shp2pgsql -s 2100 -d "D:\CHECK DATA-group\2016\Ayomi\JULY\12FCP151Sup88Sh99\121800151s00088s0099\CM121800151s00088s0099Poly.shp" | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d ssh -U postgres';`

If password is not the issue, this should be it.

Answer (score 1):

`psql` requires password to be entered which you can supply by [creating a `.pgpass` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html).

or by setting the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable (Not recommended as per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html))

> Use of this environment variable is not recommended for security
>   reasons, as some operating systems allow non-root users to see process
>   environment variables via ps; instead consider using a password file

But for a quick check you can try adding

```
putenv('PGPASSWORD=password');
getenv('PGPASSWORD');
```

in your php code before the command.

---

From [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

> **output**
>
> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing
>   whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if
>   the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the
>   end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
>   call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().
>
> **return_var**
>
> If the return_var argument is present along with the output
>   argument, then the return status of the executed command will be
>   written to this variable.

check the `$out` and `$ret` variables for the output and status of the executed command.

Comment: When i insert data to the postgis database(ssh) manually using the shp2sql tool it automatically created a table in the data base.So should  i first create a empty table here before  run this code?

Comment: Sorry, table is not the issue. I forgot that it is generated automatically. How are you passing the password for psql?

Comment: Actually ,I don't have a correct idea.Normally my ssh database has a password.If it is so,how should I add it?

Comment: For a quick check try adding

`putenv('PGPASSWORD=password'); getenv('PGPASSWORD');`

in your php code before the command.

or

`shp2pgsql -s 2100 -d /D:\CHECK DATA-group\2016\Ayomi\JULY\12FCP151Sup88Sh99\121800151s00088s0099\CM121800151s00088s0099Poly.shp | PGPASSWORD=password psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d ssh -U postgres`

For more info on setting `PGPASSWORD` Check this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/258058/104216)

Comment: I tried all these 3 methods.Still no positive results

Comment: can you share the code on how you did that and update?

Comment: <?php
putenv('PGPASSWORD=postgres');
getenv('PGPASSWORD');
$command = 'shp2pgsql -s 5235 -c C:\wamp\www\ssh\postgres\12.shp | PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d ssh -U postgres';
exec($command,$out,$ret);
?>                                                                                                                
 This is my complete code.  I just copy the shape file to another location(C:\wamp\www\ssh\postgres\12.shp)

Comment: Since you are using `putenv`, try removing the `PGPASSWORD` from the command. Also check if the command works in `cmd`

Comment: I tried it in cmd. This is what i entered.                                                  
shp2pgsql -s 5235 -d C:\wamp\www\ssh\postgres\4.shp | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d ssh -U postgres;                                                                                                     Then it asked the password of the DB.When I type it, it says "password authentication failed for user "postgres;".Problem is only one time this worked and shape file had gone to the DB(Not the same file).Why this happens?

Comment: If it's a problem with authentication you need to fix that first. Try this in cmd `psql -U postgres` and it will ask for a password. If you are not able to login to postgres user with your current password, try changing it https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/how-do-i-reset-the-postgres-password-for-postgresql-on-windows

Comment: when i log in to user postgres on server postgresSQL9.3(Localhost) ,I use the same password.Then I can log in to the data base manually without any problem.But same password is not recognised in cmd.If you don't mind,Could you please tell how this is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what could cause such issue. You can check this https://serverfault.com/a/597184

Comment: I think issue is type of authentication that is permitted by the database as set in pg_hba.conf