# Insert data in a PostgreSQL database using shp2pgsql in peer mode (without password for user postgres)?

Tags: postgresql, shp2pgsql

### Context

I wish to add some data that are for the moment in [ESRI shapefiles](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) into a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database.

To do so, I am using the [`shp2pgsql`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage) (`RELEASE: 2.4.3 (r16312)`) tool from an [Ubuntu server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) (`18.04 bionic`).

The command I usually use is:

```
sudo -u postgres shp2pgsql -s 4326 my_shapefile.shp \ 
| psql -h <hostname> -d <databasename> -U <username>
```

as described here for example: [How to import using shp2pgsql?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39238/how-to-import-using-shp2pgsql)
here: [How to specify a password with shp2pgsql using CentOS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258052/how-to-specify-a-password-with-shp2pgsql-using-centos)
or here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/import_export.html?highlight=shp2pgsql
(*but none of them answer the current question*)

and where `<username>` is the default `postgres`, which is "derived" from the operating system postgres user created when installing PostgreSQL. So the connection mode in the `pg_hba.conf` is set to `peer` and I'd like to keep it so for the moment. That's also why, I don't want to define a password for the user `postgres` in PostgreSQL.

But by using the previous `shp2pgsql` command, I am always asked for the `postgres` password, which naturally doesn't exist.

### Question:

How to avoid using a password prompt for the default user `postgres` while using `shp2pgsql`, hence keeping the advantage of the `peer` connection?

### Updates

#### 2020.02.03:

[@Ian Turton's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/349418/65370):

My first try is to switch directly to the user `postgres` as suggested:

```
$ sudo su postgres
```

and then, from the `postgres@hostmachine` terminal:

```
$ shp2pgsql -s 4326 my_shapefile.shp \
  | sudo -u postgres psql -h <hostname> -d <databasename> -U <username>
```

which in return gave me:

```
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

2nd try; I thought the sudo `-u` flag was doing the job of running the following command for the given user, and was, let's way [somehow better than switching to that user explicitely](https://serverfault.com/questions/601140/whats-the-difference-between-sudo-su-postgres-and-sudo-u-postgres) or [less naughty](https://xkcd.com/838/).
So I also tried to add `(... ) | sudo -u postgres psql (...)` after the pipe but the prompt keeps asking me for a password. And when I give one, whatever it is, it ends on; `sql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`. I wonder why the difference with the first try?

3rd try, same as previous, but while having logged me as `root` -> I am still asked for a password for the `postgres` PostgreSQL user.

Comment: GDAL with `ogr2ogr` works perfectly too and not limited to shapefile format : `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=$HOST user=$USER dbname=$DBNAME" ./my_shapefile.shp -nlt geometry -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=id -nln public.my_postgis_table -progress`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be unix user `postgres` for peer connections to work so do `su postgres` and then run the `shp2psql` command in that shell. Or alternatively you could do:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 my_shapefile.shp \ 
 | sudo -u postgres psql -h <hostname> -d <databasename> -U <username>
```

But better practice would be to set `$PGPASS` to the password so you don't need to type it in.

Comment: See edit of main post for an update. The `postgres` user of `psql` benefits the user login as `sudo -u postgres` to enter the `psql` terminal because of the `peer` mode. Actually I can access the `psql` terminal without any problem. So I do not have any password for that user. Should I set one to use `$PGPASS` then?

Comment: If you are postgres then you don't need the `sudo`

Comment: yes you would need a password to be set (good practice in itself) for the PGPASS option